# UBUNTU - WIFI not working - hp pavilion aero laptop 13-be0008ur

Tags: 20.04, wireless, hp

I recently bought a laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. Wi-fi does not work, although there is a driver, I checked. When I turn on the laptop, wi-fi works for a little time (less than a minute), and then disappears. After that, the laptop no longer sees the available networks. Tell me, please, what could be the reason for this and how to fix it?

**output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command:**

```
    01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]

    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:884d]

    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce, rtl8821ce
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:f1aa] (rev 03)

    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:390f]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

[image]

**the result of: lsmod | grep 8821**

```
rtw88_8821ce           16384  0
rtw88_8821c            94208  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_pci              24576  1 rtw88_8821ce
rtw88_core            200704  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_8821c
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Can you share your screen to show what the icon of the wifi is showing when it is disconnected?
if not, they are a couple of things that you can try to ensure that the wifi is working correctly. The first thing is (which you have already done), Go to Additional Drivers tab and see if it suggests installing wifi drivers. If that's the case, select the driver and click Apply Changes button. Wait for a couple of minutes for it to be installed. Go to system settings and see if it shows the wireless connections now. And if that doesn't work, Have a look at this other similar question that was asked

Comment: @Pilot6 I have edited

Comment: I have added a screen

Comment: Are two drivers loaded? Please edit your question to show the result of: `lsmod | grep 8821` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Why two? I have edited

Comment: rtw88_8821ce doesn't work very well. Please follow the process at the dupilcate.